# How to save data in a text file as the user presses the home button on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to save my data into a text file when the user presses the home button.
How to do so?

Answer (score 6):

Implement [`applicationWillTerminate:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW28) in your app delegate.  Do whatever you need to do to turn your data into text, and save it.

Comment: also, make sure you don't spawn any threads to do the heavy lifting of your save process. Once applicationWillTerminate is called, you can't create new threads or they terminate immediately. I had a threaded save function, and it took forever to find the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Implement [applicationWillTerminate:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:) in your application delegate. Save your application's data in that method.

Answer (score 2):

Note that applicationWillTerminate is only a kindness to your application, and if it takes too long your application will be closed down anyway.

It's way better, if possible, to update the file in question periodically so a failed save at the end will not matter.