# What is the fastest way to write a large file on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, performance

This app I'm working on allows the user to take pictures, and saves them locally (a small thumbnail image via Core Data, and the full-size image in the documents directory).

I'm finding that writing the image file to the documents directory takes a long time, though -- 8 seconds on my iPhone 3GS, even longer on my iPhone 3G, and on the first-gen iPod touch.

I write the file this way:

```
[imgData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

The iPhone's camera app seems to write the images to the filesystem very quickly. I could do the writing in a thread, but I'm concerned about the user possibly quitting my app before the thread finishes.

Answer (score 2):

- A closely related question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587380/how-does-the-default-camera-iphone-app-manages-to-save-a-photo-so-fast), and the general opinion is that the 
  iPhone's camera app uses undocumented internal API calls. I'm personally not sure if this is true, I think it's more likely that the iPhone app can persist in the background until the image is saved, a "commodity" not yet available to third party apps on non-jailbroken devices.
- Perhaps you should try indeed using a thread to save your image, but in a more data-oriented way, in byte chunks. This way, if the user presses the home button, in your `- (void) applicationWillTerminate(UIApplication *)application` method from the app's delegate, you could finalize the process of data saving to disk. This will only buy you [an extra 5 seconds](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html), though, but it's better than nothing at all. Similar recommendations have been given [on saving a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151473/how-to-save-data-in-a-text-file-as-the-user-presses-the-home-button-on-iphone). Hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: The writeToFile:atomically option is better than writing out small chunks at a time, because you know you'll either have a whole file or not...  the background thread is a good idea.

Comment: Do consider taking advantage of the extra 5 seconds in applicationWillTerminate.